# Is Open XML the best Library to handle Office-Documents in a multithreaded server-side application?

Tags: openxml, server-side

We want to integrate a powerful Office-Support in our application. Changing and creating of Office-Documents should be supported. In addition everything has to work multithreaded on a server. Do you think Open XML is the best Library for our purpose? Besides a .Net-Library is recommended.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20120603/alternatives-to-ms-openxml-sdk/20234516#20234516). it's worth taking your time to learn OpenXML than learn some other thrid party library that wont give the same amount of features as any other library.